# 4-Port Ethernet to PCIe Options

Tags: ethernet, pci-express

We are developing a distributed multi-channel data acquisition system. We are using 100BASE-TX for data transmission.

However the data throughput requires a minimum of 4 Ethernet cables to the PC, each of which is estimated to be at ~80% throughput capacity, i.e 4*100Mb/s input lines. As switches are time multiplexed, that option is unsuitable.

I have found a number of 4-port Ethernet to PCIe adapters, however **any advice on specifications required for a host machine?** Some of these adapters look like dedicated units for particular servers.

A further question would be how the OS identifies each Ethernet port? I've created Ethernet listeners on Java before but not via PCIe and not multiple RJ45 connectors.

Comment: Any particular reason why Gigabit Ethernet is unsuitable?

Comment: We are required to use 100BASE-TX due to use of other equipment dotted around the testing bay, along with restrictions on available PHY and MAC IPcores

Comment: @user2286899, why not Gigabit Ethernet to a switch with the links from the switch running as 100basetx

Comment: On just about any reasonable OS (Linux, OSX, Windows), assuming you have the correct driver for the card, you will see 4 different interfaces, just like 4 separate 1-port cards. For example, `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2` and `eth3` on a Linux system.